# How to fix Page not found (404) error in django 2.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to django with little bit knowledge in django MVT concept,

my question is about django app,i getting this silly error but i dont know hows is come ,I checked again and again everything in code ,and its all on right way but i don't know hows not working it.

[image: Page not found (404)]

- MyProject Name : fusion
- My App Name : django_adminlte
- python 3.7
- django 2.0
- MySql

My Error :

```
 Page not found (404)
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/emp

 Using the URLconf defined in fusion.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='login']
home/ [name='home']
signup/ [name='signup']
employee/ [name='emp']
show/ [name='show']
edit/<int:id>
update/<int:id>
delete/<int:id>
accounts/

The current path, emp, didn't match any of these.
```

> **emp method does not redirect to show method**

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_adminlte.forms import EmployeeForm
from django_adminlte.models import Employee

def emp(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = EmployeeForm (request.POST) # here "form" is one varible
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            form.save()
            return redirect("/show")
        except:
            pass
else:
    form = EmployeeForm()
return render(request,"employee/employee_index.html",{'form':form})

def show(request):
employees = Employee.objects.all()
return render(request,"employee/show.html",{'employees': employees})
```

---

```
urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django_adminlte import views

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

path('',views.login,name='login'),
path('home/',views.home,name='home'),
path('signup/',views.signup,name='signup'),

path('employee/',views.emp,name='emp'),
path('show/',views.show,name='show'),
path('edit/<int:id>',views.edit),
path('update/<int:id>',views.update),
path('delete/<int:id>',views.delete),

path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

---

```
HTML

{% extends 'adminlte/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<!-- Horizontal Form -->
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/emp">
    {% csrf_token %}

<div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-lable"></label> 
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Enter Details</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-lable">Employee ID : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ form.eid }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-lable">Employee Name : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ form.ename }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-lable">Employee Email : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ form.eemail }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-lable">Employee Contact :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ form.econtact }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

*Thanks!!*

Comment: `url(r'^emp/', 'django_adminlte.views.emp', name = 'emp')` try this instead

Comment: Thanks @user5173426,its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the url tag in template with your path reference name. you can check from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

In your example you define reference name "emp" for "employee/" path so you can use `<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="{% url 'emp' %}">` and `<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/employee/">` both.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the url pattern to something like:

```
url(r'^emp/', 'django_adminlte.views.emp', name = 'emp')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def emp(request):
try:
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmployeeForm (request.POST) # here "form" is one varible
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect("/show")
            except:
                pass
    else:
        form = EmployeeForm()
    return render(request,"employee/employee_index.html",{'form':form})
except TemplateNotFound as e:
    return render('404.html')
```